# How to apply if condition when it's parameter is coming into a variable?

Tags: php

I have assigned a condition into a **variable**. Then I tried to put that variable as a parameter of a **if** statement. But the code is not working. Please check my code:

```
$a = 8;
$final_str = '$a == 10';

if($final_str) {
    echo 'Output 1';
} else {
    echo 'Output 2';
}
```

The desired output should be **Output 2**. But it is not working. I always see **Output 1**. Please help me in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you echo '$a == 10' and see what you're feeding into the clause to start. It's a string ;) You want something more like $a == 10 which results in a boolean value?

Comment: Can you please explain your suggestions as a full code. I just need a solution. I can not change the first 2 lines. It is the main logic what I wanted to do. So please tell how can I solve this?

Comment: There we go, hope it makes sense if not let me know I will try further to clear up your confusion with this.

Comment: Also edited to add a reference to eval in case you are trying to create the clause dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your request, the real problem here is this line of code:

```
$final_str = '$a == 10';
```

Although you have said that you cannot change the first two lines of code as it is what you have intended, I think that what you have intended and the result of this are two different things.

You see, you are defining `'$a == 10'` which is interpreted literally as a string value.

So you are trying to do something like:

```
if ('some string') ...
```

The result of this is true because a string that is not empty is a truthy value.

I think your intention however, was to test if the variable `$a` is equal to the integer value of 10?

In which case you actually need to do:

```
$final_str = $a == 10;
```

The result of this can be true or false depending on whether the variable `$a` is equal to 10 or not, that way your if condition will reflect the desired result?

EDIT:

If however you are trying to create some PHP code dynamically within your string you'd need to [run it through eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) and here is [more information relating to the usage](https://objectiv.co/how-to-execute-php-code-in-a-php-string/).

EDIT 2:

I would rather try to re-factor this into something more like:

```
$thisPage = 8;
$truthyPages = array(10,20);

if (in_array($thisPage,$truthyPages)) {
  echo 'positive output';
} else {
  echo 'negative output';
}
```

Or maybe even:

```
$a = 8;
// Step 1
$final_result = $final_result || $a == 10;
// Step 2
$final_result = $final_result || $a == 20;

if ($final_result) {
  echo 'success';
} else {
  echo 'failure';
}
```

Comment: You wrote this: 
$final_str = '$a == 10';
To this: 
$final_str = $a == 10;

But how you will write this: 
$final_str = "is_page('10') || is_page('20')";?

Comment: @EngrArefin You need to tackle the basics first, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. You cannot cast an operator "||" as a string and expect it to work like you think as PHP the interpreter does not work this way. `$final_str = "is_page('10') || is_page('20')"` equates to `$final_str = false "||" false`, do you see the problem? Also see the new edited part of my answer

Comment: I fixed it another way. But anyway, your answer was very helpful and so I am making your answer as solved answer.